# How to analyze packets from tshark in realtime via bash?

Tags: wireshark, packet-analyzer

I need to analyze the `IPSec` packages from this command in real time:

```
sudo tshark -i <My_Interface> -Y '(ip.addr == <My_IP>)'
```

I need to check whether an `isakmp` package is sent to set a variable as true. I can't wait until the whole sniffing process is finished to be able to read it from a pcap file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some workarounds, we have a solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ $line =~ 'ISAKMP' ]]; then echo $line; fi; done < <(sudo tshark -i <My_Interface>)
```

Instead of this simple string 'ISAKMP' we can check anything else. The `echo` command may be any other command (setting an environment variable, etc.)

Comment: should there be two space characters between `IFS=` and `read`? As is, you are testing that IFS is set to an empty string, and not a space character. Does the command work like this?

Comment: A single space. IFS=' '
IFS stands for internal field separator, I just knew it that yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into the `netsniff-ng` package in `apt`. It is a packet sniffing toolkit specifically built for Linux networks.

It works great for things like analyzing signals of pci / usb devices that do not follow their respective data protocols, in order to write custom drivers.

The following is a list of included tools, including descriptions, obtained from the output of `apt info netsniff-ng`:

- netsniff-ng: a zero-copy packet analyzer, pcap capturing/replaying tool
- trafgen: a multithreaded low-level zero-copy network packet generator
- mausezahn: high-level packet generator for appliances with Cisco-CLI
- ifpps: a top-like kernel networking and system statistics tool
- curvetun: a lightweight curve25519-based multiuser IP tunnel
- astraceroute: an autonomous system trace route and DPI testing utility
- flowtop: a top-like netfilter connection tracking tool
- bpfc: a [seccomp-]BPF (Berkeley packet filter) compiler, JIT disassembler

To find out more, you can visit the *netsniff-ng* website:

http://netsniff-ng.org/

Comment: I'll take a look on that. Thanks. So far I've been working with `tshark/wireshark` and `tcpdump`